# Json string to java object

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm having following class

```
public class ReturnData {
    public ReturnData() {
        OperationResult = Result.Failed;
        Messages = "An Error Occured";
        UpdateAvailable = "0";
        ResultData = "";
    }

    public Result OperationResult;
    public String Messages;
    public String UpdateAvailable;
    public Object ResultData;
}
```

I'm having json string like,

```
{"OperationResult":0,"Messages":"","UpdateAvailable":"","ResultData":{"SessionId":"3b44a524-fc2a-499b-a16e-6d96339a6b5b","UserName":"admin","AccoundId":null,"Roles":["Administrator"],"DisplayName":"Admin","Status":3,"Type":1}}
```

I want to assign this json string to above class.I'm using GSON for assign json string to java object.In normal class i can assign json string to java object. But for this class i couldn't assign directly. Please any one help me,
Now i'm assigning like,

```
String formatedjsonstring = {json string};
            Log.i("FORMAT STRING:",formatedjsonstring);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            ReturnData returndata = (ReturnData) gson.fromJson(
                    formatedjsonstring, ReturnData.class);
```

Comment: What error do you get? Try making your public fields private and generating public setters and getters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your Java class doesn't resemble your JSON in any way, shape or form ... you're going to have a problem with that.

- Problem #1: `OperationResult` should be an `int`
- Problem #2: You're declared `ResultData` as an `Object` ... Java doesn't work like that.

You need your POJO to match the JSON:

```
public class ReturnData {
    public ReturnData() {
        OperationResult = Result.Failed;
        Messages = "An Error Occured";
        UpdateAvailable = "0";
        ResultData = "";
    }

    public int OperationResult;
    public String Messages;
    public String UpdateAvailable;
    public MyResultData ResultData;
}

class MyResultData {
    public String SessionId;
    public String UserName;
    public String AccountId;
    public List<String> Roles;
    public String DisplayName;
    public int Status;
    public int Type;
}

ReturnData rd = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, ReturnData.class);
```

I'd also consider using Gson's `@SerializedName("name")` annotation to convert the PascalCase field names in your JSON to camelCase field names in Java.

```
@SerializedName("OperationResult") public int operationResult;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use JavaJson from sourceforge. You could pass your json string to `JsonObject .parse()`.

Try this

```
 JsonObject json = JsonObject .parse("{\"OperationResult\":0, \"Messages\":\"UpdateAvailable\"");
 System.out.println("OperationResult=" + json.get("OperationResult"));
 System.out.println("Messages=" + json.get("Messages"));
```

https://sourceforge.net/projects/javajson/

Comment: The method parse(String) is undefined for the type JSONObject

Comment: Make sure you are using `JsonObject` from the `javajson` library.

Comment: Yes i did mistake and corrected by javajson.JsonObject; Now i can print the values using json.get("OperationResult"). How can i assign this JsonObject to my java class object(ReturnData);

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
java.lang.reflect.Type  type = new TypeToken<ReturnData>(){}.getType();
ReturnData rd = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, type);
```

Comment: when i check returndata.OperationResult or something i'm getting null. But in jsonstring having value